# How does an OpenVPN tune in all the traffic going into tun0?

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, vpn, socket

First of all, I understand that the kernel routing table makes all the outbound traffic forwarded to `tun0`. However, **they're NOT going to the IP address that the local `tun0` interface has** (e.g., `10.13.10.6`), rather to the destination address (e.g., `10.13.10.5`). In this case, how does an OpenVPN hook into all the traffic going to `tun0`? As I heard, **something called a raw socket is involved,** but I want to understand how specifically it ensures this behavior.

Comment: How is routing packets via `tun0` different from routing any packets via e.g. `eth0`? These will usually also not have an IP on that interface as destination address. So what exactly confuses you? Did you read up on how TUN devices work?

Comment: @ecdsa I wonder in which method an OpenVPN can suck in all the traffic going to `tun0`. My kernel routing table shows that all outbound traffic goes to `10.13.10.5`, but my `tun0`'s IP address is `10.13.10.6`. In short, I'm curious how an OpenVPN can intercepts all the packets going to the another IP address.

Comment: As I already suggested, you should read up on [how TUN/TAP devices work](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt). Maybe that clears things up.

Comment: @ecdsa Thank you for the link. As you already expected, not completely understanding how tun/tap interfaces work was the source of my confusion. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again at the routing table (`ip route`). You'll notice there's either a `default` route to `10.13.10.5`, or a pair of `0.0.0.0/1`/`128.0.0.0/1` routes to `10.13.10.5` (which is just a trick that allows OpenVPN to keep the default route, though it becomes inactive), *and this route goes via* `tun0`.

It doesn't matter what IP `tun0` has, what matters is the *gateway* IP, which happens to be `10.13.10.5` and is on the other side of `tun0`.

So how does OpenVPN make all traffic go into `tun0`? By providing routes, just like without OpenVPN all traffic goes to `eth0` (or `wlan0`, or whateever the default route says).

OpenVPN doesn't do anything special. In particular, it doesn't use a raw socket, it creates a tun/tap interface.

**Edit**

OpenVPN doesn't "listen for traffic bound to the other end".

When the **Linux kernel** sees a network packet, it consults the **routing table** to decide what to do with the packet. If the routing table says "send all packets to gateway `10.13.10.5` via `tun0`", then that's what the Linux kernel does. OpenVPN is not involved in any way in this.

Now OpenVPN has created `tun0`, so what happens when the kernel puts a packet into `tun0` is that OpenVPN can read this packet. That's what a tun/tap interface does: It allows an application to read packets put into this interface (by the kernel), and also to write packets which will get emitted from this interface (which will also be handled like the kernel, just as if the packet came from a real network card).

No promiscous mode involved. Is the problem that you don't understand how the tun/tap interface works?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Yes. I was not completely sure how exactly tun/tap interfaces work. I sort of expected it to behave like a normal Ethernet interface. Thanks to the comments by @ecdsa and your answer, I got the idea and I should certainly look into the tun/tap documentation.

Comment: Well, tun/tap sort of behaves like a normal Ethernet interface - the only difference is that instead of the packet getting handed down to the kernel driver, which talks to the hardware and tells it to send out the packet on the LAN/WLAN, the packet will be handed to OpenVPN (or whatever application created the tun/tap interface).